# Project access though TCP/IP and website using HTTP Request

Tags: python, architecture, twisted, tornado, gevent

I am trying to make a project in which I was looking for to keep the business logic separate as like just the simple python code modules and want to connect it using TCP/IP connection and HTTP Connection as some GUI will act according to it.

The project is already in the Django, but it is difficult to make a TCP/IP connection with it.... the a HTTP request from the TCP/IP is required to make to communicate with the django and there are other some problems that`s why it is not required.

I tried the following:

1.I looked into the [HOTDOT](https://github.com/clemesha/hotdot) but, I dont want to use django for this all .... bcos the UI part just consist of the dashboard, the HTML template work is not much. And the API call use is much more to connect to the other systems that too I want to achieve asynchronously..

2.I read the twisted documentation from the [Twisted Krondo](http://krondo.com/blog/?page_id=1327), which is very explanatory and very well written,but my mind change to Gevent when I saw this [asynchronous-servers-in-python](http://nichol.as/asynchronous-servers-in-python)

3.Now, I looked in the [KISS](https://github.com/stanislavfeldman/kiss.py) which is a MVC framework for the Gevent.But the community is not very big and I am afraid to use it.

I was looking for tornado or gevent to achieve this .... 
Can anyone suggest me something good to work on it to achieve this ...

[image: Project Flow]

Comment: um... as you're already using Django for the HTTP route, wouldn't it be more realistic to put a twisted server as a logic layer in front of Django, simulating the required actions?

Comment: I cant use the Django Views functions in the Twisted.